# How to insert or realign a line comment at a predefined column in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to insert or realign comments in vscode like in emacs (i.e. M-;). In emacs a meta-; would insert a new comment at a predefined comment column if there isn't already a comment or realign the comment to the comment column if there is. This would be a nice feature. For instance 'cmd+;' would insert '// ' in javascript code. If there is an extension or keyboard shortcut definition that would do this I'd appreciate hearing about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have this working in a macro.  You will need the [macrosRE](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=l7ssha.macrosRe) extension.

In your settings.json:

```
"macros": {

  "commentTabStop":  [

     "editor.action.commentLine",

     //  go to beginning of any text on line
     "cursorHome",

    // now select all whitespace at beginning of line
    { 
      "command": "cursorMove",
      "args": {
        "to": "wrappedLineStart",
        "select": true
      }
    },
    // set your number of tab stops to place comment
    "tab","tab","tab","tab","tab","tab"
  ]
}
```

That is longer than I would have hoped but to handle creating a comment on **existing** **text** that may or may not have whitespace at the beginning.  I am assuming you want all comments to be vertically aligned no matter the amount of leading tabs/space that may have had originally.  And to work when creating comments on empty lines.

```
function fooBar() {
  const someVar;
}
```

becomes

```
      // function fooBar() {
      // const someVar;
      // }
```

Unfortunately, the internal indentation within the function is lost.  But you could just reformat that part if you uncommented the code later.  Select it and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> will fix the internal indentation.

To make the keybinding put this into your keybindings.json:

```
{
    "key": "ctrl+;",
    "command": "macros.commentTabStop"
},
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark! A good start but I don't think I was clear enough. The command should leave the code in place, if there is any, and insert a comment token and space at a point specified by a 'comment-column' variable with the cursor after it ready to insert the comment. If there is already a comment on the line, it is re-aligned to the comment-column. The original code should not be altered.

Comment: Also, I should mention: If the code is already past the comment-column, a single space is inserted and then the comment token, space sequence.